# jQuery Save Image Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

On my website I have a jQuery script that, if the download button is clicked it will open the image that you want in new window.

My question is, how can I make this script when you click the button the image will save automatically and not open in a new window.

My code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#download-btn').click(function(){
                var size = $('#size').val();                
                window.open(size);
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First I try [jqueryfiledonwloader](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) but not work on image file,after a some searching I found below solution,This work for me charmly,try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#download-btn').click(function(){
     var link = document.createElement('a');
                  link.href = '/sites/default/files/toy/jpeg/image-1419683919_4851.jpeg';  // use realtive url 
                  link.download = 'MyToy.jpeg';
                  document.body.appendChild(link);
                  link.click();     
           });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi sir how about javascript button onclick get elementbyid file upload to project directory I cant find a certain script for that please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218454/how-can-we-send-data-in-mysql-when-the-form-has-set-to-enctype-multipart-form-d

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 250px;" data-image="/media/result/online_resultjpg_Page68.jpg" data-exam="GMO" data-roll="110211" onclick="downloadCertificate(this);" >Download Certificate</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadCertificate(obj){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    const image = $(obj).data("image");
    const img_ext = image.split(".");
    const ext = img_ext[img_ext.length - 1];
    link.href = image;
    link.download = $(obj).data("exam") + "_" + $(obj).data("roll") + ext;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Yuseferi script solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27667734) could be transformed into a simple anchor tag we put before the closing of the `#download-btn` one:

```
<a href='/sites/default/files/toy/jpeg/image-1419683919_4851.jpeg'
   download='MyToy.jpeg'>MyToy.jpeg</a>
```

By the way, `download` is a standard HTML5 [anchor tag (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) attribute and, in [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement), it is flagged "experimental": maybe because of unwanted side effect. Still Yuseferi solution should be full proof.

Comment: The anchor tag does not have an attribute `download`. https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/

Comment: @m02ph3u5, `download` attribute is part of the newest HTML5 [anchor tag (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and it is still experimental as an [HTMLAnchorElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement).