# How to get image from Image control and save into local directory as jpeg image in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, image, save

i am loading image from asp.net handler as below> handler fetches image using web service. Handler returns as bytes[] data.

```
<asp:Image ID="image1" ImageUrl="~/Handler1.ashx?id=1" runat="server"></asp:Image>
```

Now, I have image in the web page. I have save Image button in the web page. When button clicked, I want to save this image into local directory (c:\images) as a jpeg image. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code for handler, which returns image data:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        bool isSave = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["save"]);

        int imgId;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["id"]) || Int32.TryParse(context.Request["id"], out imgId))
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        byte[] imageData = LoadImageFromWebService(imgId); //load image from web service

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", imageData.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0} filename=image.jpeg", isSave ? "attachment;" : String.Empty));
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageData);
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Change asp.net page as follows:

```
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Handler1.ashx?id=1" runat="server"></asp:Image>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" OnClick="OnImageClick" runat="server" />
```

In this case your `OnImageClick` handler in page will be:

```
protected void OnImageClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Handler1.ashx?id=1&save=1");
}
```

Comment: i have already received image by using handler1.ashx. why should I use again handler1.ashx to generate image and save into the local directory.

Comment: as I already received image in image control, can I get this image from image control and save into the local directory? (simply, I want to use handler1.ashx one time only to fetch and save image)

Comment: My solution will help you in case displayed image differs from downloaded (user could see the smaller image than download for example). If you need possibility to show `Save As` dialog for displayed image, you have to use javascript. See for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753371/jquery-save-image-onclick

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must get the path of the image control

inside the click event

as

```
string path = image1.ImageUrl;
```

and then save it to the file

hope this helps you

Comment: while accessing image1.imageurl, "illegal characters" error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    Users objimage = new Users();
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Int32 theID;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
            theID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        HttpResponse r = context.Response;
        r.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        objimage.imageId = theID; //select image using id 
        Stream strm = objimage.SelectImageByID(theID);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        if (strm != null)
        {                
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            r.WriteFile("~/img/img-profile.jpg");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to save the image from image control which is already loaded with an image using handler1.ashx one time. I want to use handler1.ashx in .aspx page only one time to retrieve and save image.