# How can we send data in MySQL when the form has set to enctype="multipart/form-data" in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, multer

This **enctype="multipart/form-data"** blocking me from sending my data to mysql but it is a must for [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to work. I'm trying to store the image filename to database while the file will store to my project directory ./uploads using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) framework. I've tried different queries but nothing happen. I'm hoping for you guys which have faced the same issue like mine please take a little of your time. Thank you in advance.

```
<form class="add-music-form" action="/save" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="song-feaured-image">
            <input style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" name="featured_img"  onchange="loadFile(event)" required>
            <img id="output" class="image-preview" width="130" src="/img/rock-on.jpg" />
            <label for="file" class="attach_file" style="cursor: pointer">
            <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="title" name="title" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Band name" id="band_name" name="band_name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="audio" required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Select audio file</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <a onclick="cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

> app.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

const DIR = './assets/uploads/featured-img';

// Set The Storage Engine
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

let upload = multer({storage: storage});

// Set Database Connection
const connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'nodejs_crud'
});

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error) console.log(error);
    else console.log('Database Connected!')
});

//set view file
app.use(express.static('assets'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

//set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extend: false}));

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM music"
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('music_index');
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('music_index'));


app.post('/save',upload.single('featured_img'), function (req, res) {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO `music`(`featured_img`, `title`, `band_name`, `audio`) VALUES ('" + req.body.featured_img + "', '"+req.body.title+"', '"+req.body.band_name+"', '"+req.body.audio+"')";
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

// Server Listening
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## suggestion

[reference this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534892/multipart-file-uploads-using-nodejs)

your data that inserted into database isn't on req.body object instead some where else.
like `req.files.file` object. you can print out the log by using  **console.log('req.file' + req.file + 'req.files' + req.files)** on your app.js file

```
app.post('/save',upload.single('featured_img'), function (req, res) {

    console.log('req.file' + req.file + 'req.files' + req.files)

    let sql = "INSERT INTO `music`(`featured_img`, `title`, `band_name`, `audio`) VALUES ('" + req.body.featured_img + "', '"+req.body.title+"', '"+req.body.band_name+"', '"+req.body.audio+"')";
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

[reference](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)

Comment: @exe see the log if it is defined on req.file or req.files. If it is defined than than the data will be inserted on your database

Comment: I able to see the logs it is req.fileundefinedreq.filesundefined

Comment: req.body only not udefined

Comment: data is still undefined if i put the enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form

Comment: you have to find data that has values first.

Comment: @ji-young i tried app.post('/save', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) { 
    console.log(req.file, req.body);
      res.redirect('/');
}); the log wont appear

Comment: @exe what my intention find out the variable where the data you want is put in!!..... for instance usally http request for express framework req.body object has request messages... and data.!